# How to secure apache local sever over HTTPS with openssl?

Tags: laravel, apache, ubuntu, https, openssl

I'm using ubuntu 18.04 LTS, the laravel PHP framework and apache2 for my local server.

I cannot find anywhere how to secure this local server over https. Any help would be great!

Comment: https://www.digicert.com/csr-ssl-installation/apache-openssl.htm
...... For local server you have to have your cutoms certificate installed. Because third party certificate will not work for local servers, they must be on internet.

Answer (score 1):

Use [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/)(LetsEncrypt) for ssl certificate.

**Certbot**

Certbot is an easy-to-use automatic client that fetches and deploys SSL/TLS certificates for your webserver. Certbot was developed by EFF and others as a client for Let’s Encrypt and was previously known as “the official Let’s Encrypt client” or “the Let’s Encrypt Python client.” Certbot will also work with any other CAs that support the ACME protocol.

Follow [this](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntuother-apache) instructions